# Why won't my NAnt builds run in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, nant

My NAnt builds run fine locally on a developer machine, and locally on the command line of the Hudson server, but they will not run in my configured Hudson project.

The console output when I run a Build via the Hudson web UI is similar to the following :

> Started by user anonymous [workspace]
>   $ sh -xe
>   C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson8104357939096562606.sh
>   C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson8104357939096562606.sh:
>   fork failed: no error [1] Archiving
>   artifacts Finished: SUCCESS

I have another project configured properly that runs fine so I know the NAnt plugin is setup properly in Hudson, and that NAnt is on the system path.

Can anyone suggest possible causes as to why this build won't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic build may be configured to Execute a Shell script, rather than Execute a Windows Batch file.

Copy the command from the existing build step (the Execute Shell Script) and remove the step. Then add a new step to Execute a windows Batch File and paste the command.

Trigger the build and observe the results.

(I asked and answered this since it took me quite a while to figure out how I had mis-configured this particular build. Hopefully it'll save time or give ideas to other people trouble-shooting automation..)

Comment: Believe me, you are not the only one who mixed up the _shell script_ task with the _Execute Windows batch file_ task. ;)